# Step functions and Integrability

Tags: integration, continuity, step-function

**Definition**: A step function $g$ on $[a, b]$ is a bounded function on $[a, b]$ that has only finitely many jump discontinuities at $c_{0}, c_{1}, c_{2}, \ldots, c_{k}$ in $[a, b]$ and is constant on each interval $(c_{j-1}, c_{j})$.

Let $f$ be in $R[a, b]$. Given any $\epsilon>0$, prove that there exist step functions $g$ and $h$ such that

$i)$ $g(x) \leq f(x) \leq h(x)$, for all $x$ in $[a, b]$.

$ii)$ $0 \leq \int_{a}^{b}[f(x)-g(x)] d x<\epsilon \quad$ and $\quad 0 \leq \int_{a}^{b}[h(x)-f(x)] d x<\epsilon$.

What are the common strategies in such related problems? Working with step functions reminds me of the bounded variation and saltus functions, but for this particular scenario, there seems to be some helpful properties or lemmas that should be implemented, specifically the precise value of integral of the step functions in terms of discontinuous points.

Comment: Seems like there must be certain assumptions on the nature of $f$.

Comment: This is annoying to type, but one idea is to for each $n,k$ consider the sets where $f$ is between $k2^{-n}$ and $(k+1)2^{-n}$, for $k=0,1,...,n2^n-1$ and the set where $f\geq n$. Well, also the similar sets for the negative values. An initial though could be to take the simple functions that take values $k2^{-n}$ or $(k+1)2^{-n}$ on those sets. Those are not step functions yet. Next you approximate those sets by intervals, from inside and from outside and it is with those intervals that you then define the step functions. I am pretty sure, someone has typed it in this website before.

Comment: @user58697 I guess these assumptions would be necessary since there have not been any mentions about the nature of giving function $f$

Comment: @RobArthan I am so sorry, wanted to include the "saltus" functions. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: @plop Would it be possible if you elaborate more on what exactly do you refer to when saying "Next you approximate those sets by intervals, from inside and from outside and it is with those intervals that you then define the step functions." It seems very vague on how this could be achieved.

Comment: @plop It would be strongly appreciated if you could provide more details and specified solution so that we could see the big picture and details of it!

Comment: What is index 1 in the summation part? Would it be possible if you provide detailed proof of this problem? Such short comments never illustrate the true nature of the proof!

Comment: What is the set of functions $R[a,b]$?

Comment: What do you mean by a set of functions in Riemann integrable set?

Comment: @OliverDiaz Could you please clarify what is "$1$" in your functions $h$ and $g$? And how these will help you to get the desired result of inequalities?!

Comment: @Snowflake: $\mathbb{1}_A(x)$ is the function that takes value $1$ if $x\in A$, and $0$ otherwise. If you think a little about this, you notice that the $h$ and $g$ functions corresponds to some upper and lower Darboux summations.

Comment: @OliverDiaz To be honest, I still can not figure out what you mean (what is id, x, and A), could you please exemplify more?! Can you prove the inequalities? It is really obscure honestly saying

Comment: @OliverDiaz At least, what is "id" corresponding to?

Comment: @OliverDiaz Honestly speaking, your defined functions of $h$ and $g$ are a little bit different from how you mentioned the new function above. Could you please elaborate on your functions $h$ and $g$ if there are needed modifications there?! Meaning that, is your A the half-open interval?

Comment: @OliverDiaz And if true, how could you prove the second inequality involving integral? I guess first one is rather intuitively easy to grasp

Comment: @Snowflake: Let me know if things are clearer now. Of course, we are using the positivity property of the Riemann integral , that is whenever $\phi$ and $\psi$are Riemann integrable over $[a,b[$ and $\phi\leq \psi$, then $\int^b_a\phi\leq\int^b_a\psi$. Whether you are using the half open or closed set is of no consequence, this are changes on points which as you know, do not change the value of the integral.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Brilliant, now everything became super clear, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$, then there exists a partition $\mathcal{P}=\{a=x_0<\ldots<b=x_n\}$ such that
$$U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\varepsilon$$
where
$$\begin{align}
U(f,P)&=\sum^n_{j=1}M_j(x_j-x_{j-1})\\
L(f,P)&=\sum^n_{j=1}m_j(x_j-x_{j-1})
\end{align}$$
where $M_j=\sup_{x\in[x_{j-1},x_j]}f(x)$, and $m_j=\inf_{x\in[x_{j-1},x_j]}f(x)$. Define the step functions
$$\begin{align}
g(x)&:=\sum^n_{j=1}m_j\mathbb{1}_{(x_{j-1},x_j]}(x)\\
h(x)&=\sum^n_{j=1}M_j\mathbb{1}_{(x_{j-1},x_j]}(x)
\end{align}$$

Clearly $g\leq f\leq h$, and $L(f,P)=\int^b_a g\leq \int^b_a f\leq \int^b_a h= U(f,P)$. The rest follows easily:
$$\begin{align}
\int^b_a (f -g)&\leq U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\varepsilon\\
\int^b_a (h -f)&\leq U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\varepsilon
\end{align}$$

Comment: Brilliant, this is just amazing!

Comment: @Snowflake: Glad it is clear now. Cheers!